# Remove CSS class from VueJS Boostrap component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to overwrite a VueJS Bootstrap component and I can't really make it work. I checked [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown/) few times and there's no property that I can overwrite.

I need to remove `.btn` class from anchor. Is there any possibility to do that without being necessary to rewrite entire VueJS class?

Here's the render:[image: VueJS render]

As you can see, `.btn` class is added by default. I'm trying to get rid of it. Any idea?

Comment: Looking briefly at the source code, it doesn't appear to be possible: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/button/button.js#L195

Comment: What properties of btn class are you exactly trying to override? The question may have a solution by looking it this way.

Comment: @Icode4food Oh, I didn't find that file (yet), but it seems like is a constant.... great! Thank you!

Comment: @yuri the most efficient way is to remove that class, otherwise I have to set all variables to none or 0 (zero). It not like I do need a specific part, I actually need to do a dropdown, but from a link, not from a button.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that with a scoped CSS. I did that to avoid further visual bugs for other components.